# Path unavailable error during setup

Tags: iis, iis-7, wix

I have a WiX project in Visual Studio 2012 that gives the user a choice to install the application, the server, or both. My problem is when the user selects both.

I have a directory tree similar to this:

```
<Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">
  <Directory Id="ProgramFilesFolder">
    <Directory Id="Company" Name="My company">
      <Directory Id="INSTALLDIR" Name="My application"/>
    </Directory>
  </Directory>
  <Directory Id="inetpub" Name="inetpub">
    <Directory Id ="WEBINSTALLDIR" Name="wwwroot"/>
  </Directory>
</Directory>
```

Everything is just dumped in its respective folder. I made what is basically a copy of the InstallDirDlg and the BrowseDlg with different property names to choose where the server's files will be installed. They are displayed only if the user chooses to create a new virtual application in IIS (if he chooses an existing application, a custom action just grabs its physical path).

Everything works fine up until I click the next button when I've chosen to create a new application. The setup hangs for a little while (it doesn't when I choose an existing application) and then gives me a fatal error message: `The specified path 'WEBINSTALLDIR' is unavailable.` (Error 1314)

I've debugged all my custom actions (System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Launch()) and they all work and I've checked my logs, but there's nothing I can see that could make it go wrong. Every property is set to what it should be.

**UPDATE**

Here are all the references to `WEBINSTALLDIR` in my project (and `WIXUI_WEBINSTALLDIR`, equivalent to `WIXUI_INSTALLDIR`, and `_WebBrowseProperty`, equivalent to `_BrowseProperty`):

```
<Property Id="WIXUI_WEBINSTALLDIR" Value="WEBINSTALLDIR"/>

...

<Control Id="PhysicalPath" Type="PathEdit" X="20" Y="160" Width="320" Height="18" Property="WIXUI_WEBINSTALLDIR" Indirect="no" />

...

<Feature Id="Server" /*snip*/ ConfigurableDirectory="WEBINSTALLDIR">

...

<ComponentGroup Id="Server" Directory="WEBINSTALLDIR">

...

<Property Id="_WebBrowseProperty" Value="WEBINSTALLDIR"/>

...

<Publish Dialog="WebInstallDirDlg" Control="Next" Event="SetTargetPath" Value="[WIXUI_WEBINSTALLDIR]" Order="1">1</Publish>
<Publish Dialog="WebInstallDirDlg" Control="ChangeFolder" Property="_WebBrowseProperty" Value="[WIXUI_WEBINSTALLDIR]" Order="1">1</Publish>
```

**UPDATE 2**

I've noticed, in the logs, that when I use an application that does exist, `WEBINSTALLDIR` is not mentioned while the UI is active, but it is when I choose a non-existent application.

Comment: Just a quick check, does your property have the attribute `Secure="yes"` set?

Comment: @NatalieCarr No, but I don't see why that would matter. I don't have it set for the application's install directory (`WIXUI_INSTALLDIR`) and that one works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem after a while of fooling around with it.

Turns out my `PathEdit` control hooked to my path property had `Indirect` set to no instead of yes, so it was using the name of my property as the path, instead of looking up its value.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you might not be dereferencing the property correctly and are instead treating `'WEBINSTALLDIR'` as the literal path.

Where are you referencing `WEBINSTALLDIR`?

Or the other potential reason is permissions to be able to write to that folder.

References look fine at first glance. Could be permissions. Try moving the `Directory` entry for `WEBINSTALLDIR` into the same directory as the rest of the App. If that works then it probably simply can't access the `wwwroot` folder

Comment: Added all the references to my post

Comment: Updated my answer, sounds like it might be permissions.

Comment: Nope. I moved my `WEBINSTALLDIR` under Program Files and also under My Company, but both didn't work. Thanks for the help.